# How to animate while resizing UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios4, core-animation

I saw some material on the web, but still can't quite get to where I want.
I need to animate my view downwards, making it's height bigger.

Here is my code so far. What's happening here, is that instead of my view resizing, it's just changing it's location a bit up.
If I change the proprty instead of "bounds.size" to be "transform.scale.y", it's a little better, only this time it expands the view both up and down, not just downwards.

Another thing I'm not of : are these keys just CALayer properties ? where I can find a list of these keys?

I would really appreciate help here. Thanks!

```
int x = self.btnHead.frame.origin.x;
int y = self.btnHead.frame.origin.y;
int height = self.btnHead.frame.size.height;
int width = self.btnHead.frame.size.width;


CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
[resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(width,height+50)]];
resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animationGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:resizeAnimation,nil];
animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animationGroup.removedOnCompletion=NO;
animationGroup.duration = 0.1;

[self.btnHead.layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"animations"];
```

**Edit:** posting my first code as requested - This will just change my view size, but won't animate , no matter the duration I enter.

```
    int x = self.btnHead.frame.origin.x;
    int y = self.btnHead.frame.origin.y;
    int height = self.btnHead.frame.size.height;
    int width = self.btnHead.frame.size.width;


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x,y,width ,height+BUTTON_HEIGH*2);

    self.btnHead.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
btnHead.clipsToBounds=YES
```

Solved the issue.
Not sure exacly why.

Comment: I'm guessing that setting `btnHead.clipsToBounds = YES` effectively forces a redraw like setting `btnHead.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw` would. It doesn't mention anything about that in the documentation, though. This probably happens because it is very likely that changing the `bounds` of a view with clipping turned on will show parts of its view hierarchy that were not visible before. That's how scroll views work.

Answer (score 53):

Animating the `frame` property can be problematic, but it should work correctly as long as the `transform` is the identity (that is, you haven't changed it). I just tested the following code, and it worked as expected:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.1f animations:^{
  CGRect theFrame = myView.frame;
  theFrame.size.height += 50.f;
  myView.frame = theFrame;
}];
```

Again, this won't work as expected if you've changed the `transform` property at any time. For a more bulletproof version of this animation, you need to animate the `bounds` property like you tried to with Core Animation. You still don't need to drop into Core Animation, though.

The important thing to understand here is the relationship between the `bounds` and `center` properties. All affine transforms (translate, scale or rotate) need a reference point about which to perform the transform. In the case of a `UIView` that is the `center` point. `CALayer` lets you move the reference point around via the `anchorPoint` property, but we don't need to worry about that in this case.

The reason the view scales in both directions is that the scaling operation happens around the `center`. The easiest thing to to then, is to move the `center` *y* by half the height delta. Like this:

```
myView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4f animations:^{
  CGRect theBounds = myView.bounds;
  CGPoint theCenter = myView.center;
  theBounds.size.height += 50.f;
  theCenter.y += 25.f;
  myView.bounds = theBounds;
  myView.center = theCenter;
}];
```

The final consideration is forcing the view to redraw when the `bounds` changes. For performance reasons, the view will not redraw when you change its `bounds`. However, it does redraw when you change the `frame` property (yet another quirk of the `frame` property). To force a redraw on `bounds` change, you need to set the `contentMode` like I did in the first line of the previous snippet. You probably want to set it back after the animation finishes, but that's up to you. This is also the reason your Core Animation version only changes the location and not the size. You need this line in your code somewhere before you run the animation:

```
self.btnHead.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
```

I hope this all makes sense. The `frame`, `bounds` and `center` properties can be a little confusing at first.

Comment: First, Thanks for a really great answer. Now for your points, why is it that you don't need to change the center point when you change the frame, while you do need when you change the bounds ? Anyway, it turned out that it started to animate after I put btnHead.clipsToBounds=YES.... Not sure why.

Comment: The `frame` is a convenience property (there to make laying out views easier) which describes the view's rectangle in its parent's coordinate space. The `frame` value is never stored. It is calculated from the `bounds` and `center`. So when you change the `frame`, you are actually changing the `bounds` and `center`. The `bounds` describes the view's bounding rectangle in its own coordinate space (that's why its origin is usually {0, 0}), and the `center` describes the view's position in its parent's coordinate space. So, the two code examples actually do the exact same thing.

Comment: Hi, Does that mean that I usually shouldn't touch the bounds.origin, but only the bounds.size and center when I want to change it's position on screen ( it's (x,y) ) ?   I guess changing the frame is much easier anyway.

Comment: Generally, that is correct, but if you only want to change the position, the `center` property is all you need. The `frame` is easier to use, and that's why it exists, but it is completely useless once you start mucking with the `transform`. Also, there are other factors that influence the position of a view on screen such as the `transform` and the `bounds` & `transform` of the views higher up in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 8):

Can't you just change the frame within a UIView animation block. It looks like that CABasicAnimation is not required in this case.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"resize_animation" context:NULL];
// set your duration. a long duration is better to debug
// 0.1 is really short to understand what is going wrong
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2]; 

btnHead.frame = newFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Don't you just love simplicity?

Comment: No! Tried that first thing. it doesn't work. it changes the frame size but doesn't animate.

Comment: Instead of using nil for the first parameter of beginAnimations use a valid NSString as I have posted. And please let us know whether this solves the problem. Other things are looking fine.

Comment: No, it didn't help. btw, if I change the alpha it does animate. you can try it for yourself and see that it doesn't work. moreover, I don't understand why changing the "bound.size" like in the first code snippet I posted, will just move the view up and won't stretch it down.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Mac with me now. So can't run the code. As alpha change is animating, there must be some minor mistake with the frame. Frame is an animatable property, it should also animate like alpha. Let's see whether other members can find out the bug.

Comment: Does [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; help?

Answer (score 2):

clipsToBounds is the solution.

Explanation:
clipToBounds is a property that specifies if *subviews* should be cropped or not. So if a *subview* is bigger than its superview it will be cropped if you set `"superview.clipToBounds=YES"`. In the case of this post the superview WAS resized but there was no visible difference for the user, because *subviews* were drawn even if they were outside of the frame.

It's a little bit tricky, because there is no visible link with the animation, but that's why THIS property makes the difference.