# iPad - How to move and resize a label

Tags: ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to move and resize a label, but what happens is the label resizes immediately then moves into position. I first tried simply the commented out lbl.frame line. Next I found this question:

[How to animate while resizing UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586297/how-to-animate-while-resizing-uiview)

And added all the other code except for the contentMode. This did what I wanted, but the Label's font did not adjust downwards as the label shrunk. ( I tick adjust to fit in xib ). Finally adding the contentMode line gave me the same result as my original frame line - shrink immediately first them animate the move.

```
    lbl.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
                         //lbl.frame = CGRectMake(x, mStartingLine.frame.origin.y+mStartingLine.frame.size.height, 100, 100);
                         CGRect theBounds = lbl.bounds;
                         CGPoint theCenter = lbl.center;
                         theBounds.size.height = 100;
                         theBounds.size.width = 100;
                         theCenter.y = mStartingLine.frame.origin.y+mStartingLine.frame.size.height+50;
                         theCenter.x = x;
                         lbl.bounds = theBounds;
                         lbl.center = theCenter;
                     }
                     completion:nil
     ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the auto text resizing feature doesn't work with Core Animation.

What I would suggest doing is to set the label to it's final size (using it's bounds) then apply a transform to it that shrinks it back down to it's starting size. The end effect of those things is that it should stay at the same apparent size.

Finally, use animateWithDuration:animations: to set the view's transform back to the identity transform, so it grows to it's new size.

I don't know what drawing artifacts this will cause - you'll have to try it.